# Possible to open iPhone Safari and target a specific window?

Tags: iphone, safari, window, target, openurl

I have an app that uses OAuth to authenticate, which means the user must be directed to the website to authorize the application.  I prefer to make it obvious to the user that they are using a standard browser to authorize at the original site rather than just using a web view to show the content within my app.  However, every time they are directed to Safari (via openURL), it launches a new Safari window and once Safari has 8 windows open, it simply fails to work at all.

I'm wondering if there is an equivalen to the "target" attribute of an anchor tag in html which would allow me to cause all openURL calls from my application to open in the same window.

There is other functionality that I can expose via the web application, creating a hybrid app between native iphone functionality and web app functionality in Safari, but if I have to launch a new window every time I switch between the app and Safari, it becomes unworkable.  The Youtube app is obviously able to return the user to the previous page after showing a video, but that might well be a custom plugin in Safari for iphone.  Also, while returning to the previous page is somewhat useful, sending them to a new URL in the existing window really opens up a lot of possiblities.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to pass a target parameter to `openURL:`.

What I noticed about Safari is that it won't open another tab if the page you are opening with `openURL:` is/was already open in Safari. It just reloads that page. This might sound trivial and not helpful but perhaps you could use it to your advantage if you can make your web application only use one page. Different views or states could be expressed with `#anchor` tags.

An example is http://m.flickr.com. Notice their URL structure? It goes http://m.flickr.com/#/home, http://m.flickr.com/#/explore/interesting/, http://m.flickr.com/#/search and so on. All of these are different web pages to the user but to Safari it's all the same page.

Comment: That's actually very helpful.  I'm sure I can do something useful with that.  Thanks

Comment: Hmmm.  Just tested this and it doesn't actually work at all. Safari on the iphone still launches a new window for each call to openURL, even if the URL is 100% identical, let alone if it varies by anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found iOS 6.0.1 Safari will open the same tab with a simple hashtag, without the slashes. So with the above example http://m.flickr.com, openURL to http://m.flickr.com#someinfo opens to the same tab.

In your webpage, use window.location.hash to return the params. In the above example it will return #someinfo.