# Opening my JQTouch Iphone WebApp for the home icon, why every external link open in another safari window?

Tags: hyperlink, iphone, jqtouch

Using the JQTouch library, usely links like the following *...* should open the new page in the **SAME** window. That works fine when I go to the site using Safari **BUT** when I launch the site from the home saved icon, it opens a fullscreen site and on the first link it opens a **NEW** Safari window. How can I make it stay in the same original fullscreen window?

Comment: could you post some code, including the an anchor tag with their ancestor elements? e.g. <ul><li><a href="...">a link</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the target to _webapp.  E.g:

```
<li class="arrow"><a href="some_page.html" target="_webapp">Some Page</a></li>
```

and then it will load on the same page.

Comment: Looking for `window.name`, I didn't see anything like '_webapp' so it didn't work. But I liked the idea and I tried adding `window.name = '_webapp'` at the beginning of my page. It doesn't work when using fullscreen mode: it still opens a new Safari page.

Comment: It has nothing to do with window.name, it is part of the underlying jqtouch code, when an anchor is clicked, jqtouch runs some code in the background which overrides the default behavior, adding _webapp is part of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into manifest files.

The manifest file declares what files (html, javascript, css, jpgs etc.) that the iPhone should cache in order to make a webapp work offline. A part of the manifest file is used to declare which URLs are OK to use when in full screen (webapp) mode.

Specifically look at NETWORK in manifest files.

Example:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

This should allow access to any URL you like, and stay in webapp mode.

Alternatively use target="_self" - I haven't seen target="_webapp" anywhere.

/Mogens

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651861/possible-to-open-iphone-safari-and-target-a-specific-window) is to change the way you write your links for a mobile app.  Rather than `a href='link.url'` you'd write `a href="javascript.window.location.href='link.url'"`

*Dislaimer:* I haven't personally tried this yet, so I can't guarantee it will work.  But logically, it does make sense.

Comment: I tried with `href="#" onclick="window.location.href='link.url'"`, it worked BUT I had wierd JQTouch behaviour (my current user was getting disconnected, sometime the link didn't do nothing, ...) ... well I backed off for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using target="_webapp" works only if you remove the rel="external", you cannot have both.