# Switching tab on iOS mobile browser is not working via a href target or even window.open window focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, browser

I've been working on this for 1 week, but no luck I can't find any answer on this.

I want to switch tab on my browser iOS mobile via javascript or html, I tested it in all browser in mac and android, it's working as expected. But in iOS mobile it's not working. I saw some articles that I need to disable popup blocker which I did.

I tried simple way like

```
<a href="http://mysite.test/test" target="custom_name">go</a>
```

> this will just create new window but when I clicked it again it doesn't switch to this tab

```
const newWindow = window.open(href,"custom_name")
```

> same thing happens in here.

I also tried

```
newWindow.focus()
```

> nothing happens

I read there's an article that iOS blocked the popup new window for security policy, not sure if this switching of tab is also included in that policy.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651861/possible-to-open-iphone-safari-and-target-a-specific-window

Comment: not sure if im doing it correct, I have this existing tab http://mysite.test/test#custom_name and on my page http://mysite.test/test I have this <a onClick={(e) => window.location.hash = 'custom_name' } > nothing happens

Comment: it doesn't switch, it only add the hash value to the current url of same window